# NameError (uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Получаю ошибку при попытке доступа на страницу:

> NameError (uninitialized constant
>   Web::Admin::Products::BrandsController::Brand):
>   app/controllers/web/admin/products/brands_controller.rb:3:in `index'

Мой Controller:

```
app/controllers/web/admin/products/brands_controller.rb
```

Моя модель

```
app/models/product/brand.rb
```

Мой routes.rb

```
.....
.....

scope module: :web do

  namespace :admin do
    namespace :products do
      resources :brands     
    end 

    resources :products do
      scope module: :products do          
        resources :product_types
      end      
    end

  end
end

.....
.....
```

Действие `Index` в app/controllers/web/admin/products/brands_controller.rb:

```
def index 
  @search = Brand.all 
  @brands = @search.result(distinct: true) 
end
```

Comment: Вы забыли приложить строчку, на которую указывает непосредственно ошибка.

Comment: Действие `Index` в   app/controllers/web/admin/products/brands_controller.rb  

`def index  
    @search = Brand.all  
    @brands = @search.result(distinct: true)  
end`

Comment: В вопрос, не в комментарии. И, кхм, там ясно написано, что нет константы `Brand`. Она может быть много где.

Comment: Разве в рельсах нет соглашения, если например контролер лежит в `products` , то и модель должна лежать в `product`, или я что-то недопонимаю? Строго не судите , только начал кодить в этой среде

Comment: Нет, такого соглашения нет. Это разные слои, в них нет смысла делать соответствие 1-к-1. Обычная практика делать несколько контроллеров на одну модель, если сценарии использования существенно разные.

Comment: спасибо за внимание, в `Index` указал `Product::Brand.all` вместо `Brand.all` и проблема решилась

Comment: Ок, пишите ответ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

спасибо за внимание, в `Index` указал `Product::Brand.all` вместо `Brand.all` и проблема решилась